# Focus on browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am facing the following scenario, and I am wondering if there is a solution to my problem (I thin there isn't one, but yeah..maybe you guys know).

So I have a restaurant that receives orders in a browser...The restaurant owner logs in to a website, and in the orders page he can see all orders that he receives...

As the restaurant doesn't get orders all the time...the employes sometimes try to kill some time at the computer...and there are 2 ways in which they can do this:
1. By opening other tabs in the same browser (like Facebook and stuff like that :))
2. By opening maybe other browsers and/or programs.

So for the employees to know that there is a new order, I use a background sound to announce them...however I was hoping to find a way to have the orders tab displayed when a new order is received...

Now in the first scenario, I can do that using `alert`...am I right or is there another way?
In the second solution I don't know if it is even possible...so maybe you can help me :)

Thanks

EDIT: So you guys are suggesting `alert`..however this only works in the first case (at least in my tests, when i was in another program for example, the orders tab wasn't brought up when using `alert`..so the `alert` only solves the problem when i am on a different tab, in the same browser )

Answer (score 0):

You may look it to **[HTML5 Notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification)** also

But it works in chrome and firefox only for now.
To play safe, I beleive alert is the only way

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.focus()` if the browser supports focus stealing. Otherwise `alert()` is your best bet.

Comment: `alert()` works differently in different browsers. May or may not work.

Answer (score 0):

if you call alert() in page firefox will focus that tab.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers by default do not allow javascript to play with the focused tab.

I will not tell you about `alert()`, since they have already told you about that ;)

I would create a chrome extension (if forcing chrome is ok) that would interact with the website and if it detects a new order, it would use the [tabs api](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html) to change the tab with the focus.

...or, I will use iptables to block anything that is not the url from the orders page, so they stop messing with facebook on work time ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would say use a popup which come up from the bottom right corner of the screen. Sound alerts can be ignored or may not work if the speakers are off. But a visual popup coming from the corner of the screen, particularly "red" in colour are hard to ignore

Comment: @AnaMaria.. does your solution work when the user in another tab of the browser?...cand you give me a link or example of how to create that popup ?